# Finding extreme points in contours with OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv3.0

I have tried to implement this [code](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/11/finding-extreme-points-in-contours-with-opencv/), but I have a trouble when I want to determine the most extreme point of the contour follow this tutorial.

```
# determine the most extreme points along the contour
    extLeft = tuple(c[c[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])
    extRight = tuple(c[c[:, :, 0].argmax()][0])
    extTop = tuple(c[c[:, :, 1].argmin()][0])
    extBot = tuple(c[c[:, :, 1].argmax()][0])
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: take a look at http://answers.opencv.org/question/64433

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from a `std::vector<cv::Point>`, you can use `std::max_element` and `std::min_element` with an appropriate comparator, that works on `x` coordinates to find *left* and *right* points, and works on `y` coordinates to find *top* and *bottom* points:

```
// Your points
vector<Point> pts;
...


Point extLeft  = *min_element(pts.begin(), pts.end(), 
                      [](const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs) {
                          return lhs.x < rhs.x;
                  }); 
Point extRight = *max_element(pts.begin(), pts.end(),
                      [](const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs) {
                          return lhs.x < rhs.x;
                  });
Point extTop   = *min_element(pts.begin(), pts.end(), 
                      [](const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs) {
                          return lhs.y < rhs.y;
                  }); 
Point extBot   = *max_element(pts.begin(), pts.end(),
                      [](const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs) {
                          return lhs.y < rhs.y;
                  });
```

Comment: The code for extRight and extBot needs to have the comparison reversed (lhs.x > rhs.x for extRight and lhs.y > rhs.y for extBot)

Comment: @bantic you're right... actually this code sucks ;) I'll rewrite it using minmax_element asap